# Require basic auth for specific IPs in nginx

Tags: nginx, http-basic-authentication, http-authentication

I have a whitelist of IPs for nginx, but in addition to this I want to require basic authentication for specific IP.

For example, allow access for these IPs:

```
198.51.100.1
198.51.100.2
```

require basic authentication for this IP:

```
198.51.100.3
```

and deny for anyone else.

How is this possible? [`satisfy`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#satisfy) directive doesn't seem to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement this with the GEO directive: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html#geo

Just a sketch using your ip address examples:

```
geo $authentication {
default "Authentication required";
198.51.100.1 "off";
198.51.100.2 "off";
198.51.100.3 "on";
...
}
```

server {
    ...
    location / {
        satisfy any;

# basic auth referencing to geo with $authentication
    auth_basic $authentication;
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    # whitelist for the inital ip address restrictions
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/ip-whitelist.conf.include;
    deny all;
}}